# ADB output on Android Device

Tags: android, debugging, logging, adb

Is there an app or utility that will allow me to view ADB output on the handset itself or a log-viewer that will allow you to inspect logs at a later time? I've seen the utilities that allow you to connect via WIFI, but I'd rather just do it on the device if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this app will show you the logcat from your phone: [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat)

Comment: @rhooligan there are a few other options I outlined in another solution for you. Hope that helps give a bit more of an overview of your options.

Answer (score 3):

[AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en) has an integrated logcat viewer.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few options here, if you are asking strictly outside of being "attached to you PC":

If you are on the same WiFi network...

1) [Remote ADB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jaja.remoteadb) allows you to run ADB without the device being "attached" **requires root**

2) [Logcat to UDP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.madzik.android.logcatudp) does not require root and not only can send this to a [Python listener](http://code.google.com/p/logcatudp/source/browse/test/listener.py) through UDP on your machine which you could save for a later date, you can also email the log to yourself from the device. (So because of that and for the fact you could theoretically forward UDP, you do not need to be on the same network.)

Local device Logcat options:

3) [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) is very popular and helpful with a variety of verbose levels and filtering available. The logs can be emailed.

4) [CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat) is becoming more popular and has all the same features as aLogcat and more UI/UX appeal.